# sh '<' syntax unexpected error

Tags: asp.net, .net, bash, shell, unix

I am struggling with running new asp.net 5 on my qnap box. As far as I understand it is a strongly modified version of debian.

As part of running installation script I got this error:

```
-sh: /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh: line 616: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
-sh: /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh: line 616: read versionOrAlias downloadUrl < <(__dnvm_find_latest "$runtime" "$arch" "$os")'
```

I run my script bu using script command like:

```
script /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
```

as stated in documentation and previous installation script.

By commenting this line out I was able to run whole script but obviously dnvm command does not work properly.

My question is:
What does it do (line with < < syntax) and how do I fix it or rewrite so that my qnap box unix can understand it.

Comment: mentioned script can be viewed here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvm.sh

Comment: `<` is redirection, `< <` doesn't make much sense. redirect the redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<(...)` is Process substitution. `/bin/sh` doesn't support it, but `/bin/bash` does. Try changing the shell.

Comment: There are a number of other bash specifics as well, like`read -p`.