# DNVM on Mac causing console errors

Tags: .net, macos, installation, runtime-error, dnvm

I just followed the directions [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/beta5/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html) for installing .NET on my mac (Yosemite 10.10) and now every time I do anything in my terminal I am spammed with this error:

```
sh: dnvm: line 125: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
sh: dnvm: line 125: ` read versionOrAlias downloadUrl < <(__dnvm_find_latest "$runtime" "$arch" "$os");'
sh: error importing function definition for `dnvm'
sh: dnvm: line 125: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
sh: dnvm: line 125: ` read versionOrAlias downloadUrl < <(__dnvm_find_latest "$runtime" "$arch" "$os");'
sh: error importing function definition for `dnvm'
```

I've tried searching for solutions, but nothing came up. I even tried uninstalling it so the errors would go away, but I'm having no luck.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know little how mac is architectured but if it is like linux then I had the same problem here: [sh '<' syntax unexpected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531554/sh-syntax-unexpected-error). Answer was:

/bin/sh doesn't support it, but /bin/bash does. Try changing the shell.

Hope it helps.